# Reset powerpoint slide programmatically

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, vsto, ms-office, office-interop

I want to perform the following Office-Powerpoint operation programmatically-

Right click on a ppt slide
Click Reset slide

Is there a method on the API to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this    `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("SlideReset")`